# Who owns CWinThread after it was created by AfxBeginThread?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am starting a thread by using `AfxBeginThread`. This returns a pointer to a new `CWinThread` object.

MSDN states that this pointer is NULL and it will deallocate everything if thread creation fails. However as soon as the thread exits after starting regularly the `CWinThread` object still exists. I am not sure if I should delete the `CWinThread` object or if this is done by MFC itself (though it does not seem so).

FYI it is not likely that the thread exits, since it should run until the application ends. However since I use it to be part of a thread pool, I do not want the `CWinThread` to hang aorund for ever.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The responsibility for cleaning up the CWinThread object depends on it's m_bAutoDelete value. The default is to delete itself. For fire and forget short running threads this is fine. It will clean up after itself.

If your thread is long running and needs to be told it's time to quit or otherwise interacted with, you will want that CWinThread handle to remain valid and not point to a self-deleted object.

If you set m_bAutoDelete to FALSE, you claim responsibility for deleting it. To play it safe with the returned pointer you should create suspended and set it to FALSE before resuming as suggested by Joseph Newcomer in his [Using Worker Threads](http://www.flounder.com/workerthreads.htm#Shutting%20down%20a%20thread%20from%20a%20view%20or%20main%20frame) article.

```
   thread = AfxBeginThread(proc, this, 
                       THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, // default: use it
                       0,     // default stack size 
                       CREATE_SUSPENDED); // let us set auto delete
   if(thread) { // protect against that rare NULL return
       thread->m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;
       thread->ResumeThread();
   }
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer. The other two answers are wrong and may cause undefined behavior.

Comment: If you have a GUI thread with m_bAutoDelete = TRUE and you observe that the thread does not exit although the user clicked the "Close" button of the main window, it may be necessary to call PostQuitMessage() in PostNcDestroy().

Comment: Note also that If you're cleaning after the thread yourself (m_bAutoDelete = FALSE), you'll still want to wait for the thread to exit before deleting the object

Answer (score 4):

I never trusted CWinThread to clean up after itself. I usually create threads and I tell MFC that I'll do the clean up, specially when the program is closing:

```
CWinThread *thread = AfxBeginThread(...); 
thread->m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;
```

You will, however, have to save the thread pointer otherwise you'll have memory leaks.

Comment: thank you, I just found out about the m_bAutoDelete member and do it as you and @fontanini suggest. +1

Comment: This answer is wrong. By the time this code attempts to set `m_bAutoDelete`, `CWinThread` object may have already deleted itself. See answer by @jla on how to use this technique correctly.

Comment: I don't agree that the answer is wrong. The key to the answer is the m_bAutoDelete, and the param to in the sample are "..." omitted for brevity. It is also imperative that CREATE_SUSPENDED, if not, your comment is correct. I do agree that @jila's answer is more complete.

Answer (score 2):

If your thread is still running, you shouldn't delete it. Once it has stopped, just use operator `delete` on the pointer returned by `AfxBeginThread` in order to free the memory used by the thread:

```
CWinThread *thread = AfxBeginThread(...);
/* ... */
// now wait for it to terminate
WaitForSingleObject(thread->m_hThread, INFINITE); 
delete thread;
```

You should store the `CWinThread` pointers until your thread/application ends, so that you can free the memory allocated for them. Otherwise, you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Upon thread termination, `CWinThread` will close the thread handle, and delete itself. Hence this code may call `WaitForSingleObject` on a closed handle, which is undefined behavior, or it may attempt to delete an object which has already been deleted. Correct approach is to use `m_bAutoDelete` on a _suspended_ thread, as explained in an answer by @jla.